# Why does freshwater attenuate signals less than seawater?

Tags: electromagnetism, water

One of the most interesting problem in underwater communication is how deep the device (i.e. submarine) could go to still be able to communicate with on-shore data centers.

The attenuation in a medium is usually explained away as a function of how conductive the medium is. http://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:649690/FULLTEXT01.pdf see fig 2.3

My question is: What is the fundamental reason as to why freshwater attenuates signals less than seawater? Is it because freshwater is more conductive than seawater?

Comment: Don't you mean that freshwater is *less* conductive?

Comment: Sorry I'm really confused. Yes freshwater should be less conductive but it transmits EM signals better, can you explain this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thesis you refer to puts values of 0.02 S on the conductivity of
freshwater and 4 S for seawater. I'm assuming that the S here stands for the SI unit
of Siemens per metre, the value of $\sim 5$ Siemens per metre
is one I have used for seawater in the past.

Submarines communicate with frequencies as low as 100 Hz.To test for a "good conductor" we compare conductivity $\sigma$ with $\omega \epsilon_0 \epsilon_r$,
where $\omega$ is the angular frequency, and $\epsilon_r$ is the
relative permittivity (about 80 for water). This comparison suggests
*both* freshwater and seawater are good conductors for waves at this
frequency. (Indeed you would not try mixing AC electricity with your bathwater, right?)

Given that, there is an easy expression for the characteristic length,
the "skin depth", that an EM wave will travel before being attenuated
by $1/e$: i.e. $ l = \sqrt{2/\mu_0 \sigma \omega}$. At these
frequencies, the skin depth in freshwater is 355m, whilst for seawater
it is 25m.

OK, but I guess you knew all that, and your question is *why* does
conductivity affect the skin depth in this way when you might
intuitively have thought that better conductors would somehow allow EM
waves to pass more freely?

The way to think about it is in term of Ohm's law and the dissipation
of energy by currents. The power dissipated by a current in a circuit
is of course $I^2 R$, but how is this related to electric field and
conductivity? If we let current density $J$ be current per unit area, so
that $I=JA$, and resistance $R
= l/\sigma A$, where $l$ is distance travelled through the
medium; then, further noting that $J = \sigma E$ in a linear conductor, we
finally get a power dissipation of $J^2 A^2 l/\sigma A = \sigma E^2 A l$.
i.e. the power dissipated per unit volume is proportional to
$\sigma$. A higher conductivity yields higher currents and more Ohmic
heating.  The heat is provided by the electromagnetic energy flux of
the waves. Thus the Poynting vector of the wave decays as it travels through the
conducting medium; the missing power (per unit volume) is equal to $\sigma E^2$.

Answer (score 1):

An electromagnetic wave consists of an electric and magnetic field that moves through space. If the space that the wave moves through is filled with electric charges, such as the ions in salt water, then the electric field will start to push these charges around. This pushing requires energy, and this energy is drained from the electric field. This is the reason why an electromagnetic signal will be attenuated in materials, which is just another way to say that the energy in the electric field is absorbed by the material.

The difference between the attenuation in different materials can therefore be explained in terms of their electrical conductivity. In for example metals, you have an electron cloud which is very easy to push around, and you therefore have a very high attenuation. In seawater, you have dissolved ions which can be pushed around, and this also leads to attenuation. In fresh water, you have a much smaller concentration of ions that can be pushed around, so there is less attenuation. Even distilled water will have some attenuation, because water molecules can react among themselves to create minute concentrations of hydronium and hydroxide ions, and moreover the water molecules themselves are electric dipoles that can be flipped around by an applied electric field. Air contains very few electric charges or dipoles compared to all the other media discussed above, and will therefore attenuate the signal very little. An ideal vacuum doesn't contain any charges or dipoles at all, and will therefore not attenuate the signal.

Comment: You're right, so I updated the answer to try to clarify that :)